# How do I make a byte array for a PNG from two Numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have two Numpy arrays (one has positional data, the other has color data), and I am trying to convert them into a byte array that could be represented as a PNG. The positional array has a shape of (N,2) and the color array has a shape of (N,3), where N=N. The 2 in the positional array is X,Y data, and the 3 in the color array is R,G,B data. I am not familiar with how the PNG file structure works, but I basically want to make the byte array store my pixel art, but with a transparent background. How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what the size of the final image is to be, but if it is to have dimensions `(nx, ny)` you can do this with NumPy and PIL:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Test: set 2 pixels in a 4x3 image.
N = 2
nx, ny = 4, 3
# Specify the colours of pixels at these (x,y) coordinates
pos = np.array([[0,0], [1,1]])
col = np.array([[0,255,255], [255,0,0]])

# Set the alpha channel of the coloured pixels to 255: opaque
cola = np.ones((N,4)) * 255
cola[:,:3] = col
# The image RGBA array: initially set all pixels to transparent (alpha=0)
img = np.zeros((nx, ny, 4), dtype=np.uint8)
# Set the pixels' colours.
img[pos[:,0],pos[:,1]] = cola

# Turn the array into a PIL Image and save it.
im = Image.fromarray(img)
im.save("image.png")
```

Comment: So, for the size of the image, I would want it to be scalable with the size of the Numpy arrays and always square. If Y>X then there should be a transparent margin on the X axis equal to the difference between the size of X and Y. Also, even though this would work for making the PNG directly, I'm trying to make a byte array that could later be converted into a PNG (I have a pretty specific workflow). Is there a way to convert the 'img' variable into bytes that would work with the PNG file format?

Comment: img is already a byte array, it's just converted through PIL to a PNG file. If you want You can set nx = ny = np.max(pos) and then calculate an offset for setting img in the appropriate dimension (half the difference between np.max(pos[:,0]) and np.max(pos[:,1]), I guess).